# Apache2 installed but localhost not working

Tags: android, apache, ubuntu

I have installed apache2 on my ubuntu 12.04 image configured for android device.
We built this image using debootstrap using this tutorial 
http://the.taoofmac.com/space/blog/2013/04/28/2330

But when I installed apache2 on it didn't work.
I have checked all conf files and nothing seems out of place.

I started the server using sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start 
and it started just fine but can't load 127.0.0.1 or localhost in browser??

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

try pinging localhost and 127.0.0.1 to make sure they're properly mapped in the os

then examine the apache config file and make sure it's running on port 80

try telnetting to localhost:80 and seeing if it answers

try running apachectl configstatus/status/fullstatus and see what it says... it may be reading a config file in a different path than what you're expecting